# Python : How can i iterate 3 row values from dataframe at a single time? And then again next 3 values at a single time?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I have a data frame -

```
Name  Rank
A     2
B     3
C     6
D     7
E     4
F     3
G     9
H     2
I     5
```

I want Rank Column 3 values at a time.
such as -

```
2
3
6
```

and Next again I want to Rank Column 3 values at a time.
such as -

```
3
6
7
```

and Next again I want to Rank Column 3 values at a time.
such as -

```
6
7
4
```

Like in this format,
you can use any way loop or any other way.
I don't know how I can do this, please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: It helps to know what things are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do

```
[df.Rank.tolist()[x:x+3] for x in df.index[0:-2]]
[[2, 3, 6], [3, 6, 7], [6, 7, 4], [7, 4, 3], [4, 3, 9], [3, 9, 2], [9, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: No, don't reinvent the wheel. So-called "rolling window" functionality is built into Pandas.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you sure , did you try rolling in pandas ~ hehe, there is no way for panda to agg object